# browser for creating mobile game app

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I don't know whether my question belongs here but I am asking it anyways. Why is there not a lot of shift in creating the game using HTML5 rather than creating a native  game app, especially for mobile application? While I understand completely and assuming my understanding to be correct, for desktop games, a native game can use the graphics card in the computer taking the hefty load of graphics processing off from the CPU. What is the case for mobile browser? Does the mobile browser allowed to have the equal amount of processing resources as the native app? As far as I think, the processor is all and all in mobile phones. If this is correct then, I would think it would be more easier to create game with browser.

Is my understanding correct? Am I missing something here? What is the catch if I want to create game app using HTML and javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A game as a native app would usually be written in a much more efficient language than javascript, for example Java on Android or Objective-C on iOS. Javascript is usually interpreted as it is run (as far as I know), and this affects the performance. Also, while you can obfuscate javascript to hide the implementation (if you want to protect your code), it isn't as effective as compiling a native app (I don't know how hard it is to reverse-engineer Java though).

However, WebGL is becoming more popular, and lets javascript code use hardware acceleration to accelerate graphics. When this is well supported on mobile devices, it might be feasible to make a complex game in the web browser. It certainly makes it more portable, and you could put it in a native WebView (or similar), for it to act like a native app.

Some examples here: http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple potential drawbacks for HTML 5, one of which has already been pointed out, is a potential performance hit.  This is sorta a big one, especially for devices that aren't capable of using WebGL.  The other really big one for me anyways, is bandwidth use.  Most phones (at least in the USA) are on fairly restrictive data plans, and thus if you're accessing the game via HTML 5, you're potentially eating into your bandwidth use every time you play, meanwhile a native app is downloaded once, and that's the last of the data usage...input lag is another biggie, particularly if your game requires specific timing.  Granted, as speeds get faster on mobile devices this becomes less and less of an issue, but it will never be equal to what can be done locally on a native app.  Lastly, as was pointed out, code hiding, you may or may not care about, but it's easier to do on a native app.